# Are there tools available for collecting logs from all devices in Android?

Tags: android, logging

I am currently working on an embedded Android application. At present, we have released our device at a small scale and are trying to diagnose some of the problems that users are reporting. Currently, we are writing our logs locally to files on the SD card, but that is obviously a very limited solution.

We have a solution in mind which would involve creating a service to upload our logs automatically, but first I was wondering if there is any standard way to gather logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a logging service like [Loggly](http://loggly.com/). Install an Android library to log to Loggly, such as [Timber-Loggly](https://github.com/tony19/timber-loggly). You can then start logging.

To make it easier to log to all of your loggers, create a logging function such as:

```
public static function dLog(String message) {
       Log.d(TAG, message);
       Timber.d(message);
}
```